# Zend framework action parameter

Tags: zend-framework, zend-controller

I want to pass an entire path as an action parameter to my controller action.

mycontroller/myaction/myparameter/path_value

e.g. path_value could be something like test/folder/folder2

I do not want to urlencode the parameter. Is it possible that in my controller action I can get the entire path as the parameter value for 'myparameter' (so, 'test/folder/folder2') instead of only 'test'.

I hope I am clear enough. Tnx in advance

Comment: you can send test_folder_folder2 then str_replace _ with / if you don't whant to mess with the routes

Comment: unless you use a custom route... this begs the question: why on earth would you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it as `<baseurl>?myparameter=test/folder/folder2`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to modify Zend's routing in order to do what you are attempting. Encoding the path may be much simpler for you. I suppose you could send this variable as a POST rather than a GET.